# ctypedef with ndarray raises "Buffer types only allowed as function local variables"

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I want to define a type on a specific numpy structure.

```
cimport numpy as np
ctypedef np.ndarray[np.int32_t, ndim=1] XX_t
```

But cython compilation fails with error:

```
cimport numpy as np
ctypedef np.ndarray[np.int32_t, ndim=1] XX_t
^
------------------------------------------------------------

x.pyx:2:0: Buffer types only allowed as function local variables
```

I have searched around, and there are explanation on `cdef`.

I do not understand why there is still such error with `ctypedef`.

Comment: I think that it is because any cdef/ctypedef declaration must refer to an underlying C type and ndarray's are not C-level but a Cython datatype. The shorter syntax `cdef int[:] var_name` could help you if you want more conciseness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says, numpy buffer types (`np.ndarray...`) can only be used in local variables / function params, not typedefs.  There is likely no fundamental reason this couldn't work, simply not implemented. Github issue here:
https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/754

As @Pierre noted in comments, cython now supports an alternative syntax for typed memorviews (`int[:]`) which do seem to work with typedefs.

```
%%cython
ctypedef int[:] XX_t

def my_fun(XX_t arr):
    return arr[0]

my_fun(np.array([1,2,3], dtype=int))
Out[6]: 1
```